# For network-bound IO, are the benefits of asynchrony greater in poor networking conditions?

Tags: asynchronous, networking

Imagine we want to launch a dozen of HTTP requests asynchronously. Does the time saved by asynchrony go up the slower your network gets?

As far as I know, we can split such a request into two parts. The first one, where we're doing some lightweight CPU-bound work (initializing and finalizing the connection - contacting the networking hardware, putting the response received into an array, et cetera). And the second one, that takes much more time, where our thread is blocked as we're waiting for the data to arrive.

The goal of asynchrony is to **process the second part of all requests made concurrently**, and (unlike the CPU-bound part) we have to wait for data the longer the slower our connection is. It shortens the waiting-for-data part, it doesn't do a thing to the cpu-bound part.

Given that, I'm inclined to draw the conclusion an asynchronous implementation saves us more time in poor networking contitions. Also, if data from the network were received instantly, the benefits of asynchrony would equal zero.

Are these conclusions true?

Comment: No. The time spent waiting for the data doesn't change.

Comment: @user207421 Why, what do you mean? Doesn't the time your network needs to deliver the (potentially large) file to you get longer as the network gets slower (whatever 'slower' means, such as low bandwidth, packet loss which means packet need to be re-transmitted if TCP, etc)?

Comment: *Of course* transmit time increases with network congestion or errors, but that's not what you're asking. You're asking about async I/O: and whether you use blocking or non-blocking or asynchronous I/O cannot possibly affect that time. If you think otherwise please explain how.

Comment: @user207421 For a single request, it cannot. I'm talking about multiple requests processed concurrently. From what I know, a bunch of requests will be completed faster if done asynchronously (unless something on your end is the slowest part of the network path), because to begin the second request you don't need the previous request to be completed in its enteriety. That is, you can initiate multiple connections and receive frames belonging to mutliple requests all at once.

Comment: Will be completed faster why? How does the network get quicker if you use a different API?

Comment: @user207421 My understanding here is that, if - for example - one of the servers you contact is slacking with responding to your request, a sync code will be stuck with that server until the request is completed, doing nothing if the server's responding slowly. An async code will be handling requests made to other servers in the meantime, without waiting for the slow server to finish.